# JasperReports: Report element Auto height in Table component detailCell

Tags: jasper-reports, alignment

ReportElement TableComponent detail Cell height changing by other detail Cell on same row(stretchWithOverflow), I need align text field vertically middle  relative to tableComponent detail Cell or align ReportElement  in detail Cell.

```
Settings not working stretchWithOverflow=true;  positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"
```

Comment: Since you have stretch with overflow to true, cells in table will adjust their height according to text in them, and this stays for full row. You cannot have different heights for different cells in same row.

Comment: Yes, but the text elements in cells have different heights in same row.

Comment: Provide stretch with overflow to each cell

Comment: Text elements might have different heights but cells will have same height.

Comment: Yes, but I need to have same height for text fields

Comment: Remove stretch with overflow then, but then text would truncate if it exceeds given boundaries.

Comment: I have added stretch with overflow specially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  fixed it changing  "RelativeToTallestObjec" - "RelativeToBandHeight"